# Showing that $Var(log(Y_i)) \approx \frac{1}{\alpha}$ if $Y_i = x_i^T\beta\epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_i \sim N\left(1, \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that $Y_i$ follows a multiplicative error model:

$$
Y_i = \mu_i \epsilon_i
$$

where

$$
\mu_i = x_i^T\beta \ \ \text{and} \ \ \epsilon_i \sim N\left(1, \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)
$$

I would like to show why:

$$
Var(log(Y_i)) \approx \frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

How can I use the Delta method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(Y) = \ln Y$, you can approximate $g(Y)$ at $E\mu \epsilon = \mu$ with first order Taylor series
$$
g(Y) \approx g(\mu)+ g'(\mu)(Y-\mu),
$$
rearranging the equation and taking square you get 
$$
(g(Y) -  g(\mu))^2\approx (g'(\mu))^2(Y-\mu)^2,
$$
by taking an expectation of each side you get
$$
Var(g(Y))\approx (g'(\mu))^2Var(Y) = \frac{1}{\mu^2}\frac{\mu^2}{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

By the delta method $\log(Y_i)-\log(\mu_i)$ is approximately distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2\cdot h)$ where $$\sigma^2=Var(\mu_i\varepsilon_i)=\frac{\mu_i^2}{\alpha},$$ and
$$h=[(\log{\mu_i})']^2=\frac{1}{\mu_i^2}.$$
In particular, $$Var(log(Y_i))=Var(log(Y_i)-\log(\mu_i))\approx\sigma^2h=\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$